# How to avoid getting message ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

How to avoid getting this kind of message

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 32
```

So far I read a couple of post here in stackoverflow, but whatever I put in my `GROUP BY` I get always same error.
I try to add `a.EndDate` also but still getting same error.

```
      SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT uta.StartDate, uta.EndDate FROM user_timesheets_absence uta
                LEFT JOIN users  u ON u.UserID = uta.UserID
                WHERE uta.UserID = 1
                AND uta.Approved = 'true'
                    AND 
                        ((
                            '2020-06-06' >= uta.StartDate
                    AND
                             '2020-06-06' <= uta.EndDate
                        )
                    OR
                        (
                            '2020-06-06' <= uta.StartDate
                    AND
                             '2020-06-06' >= uta.StartDate
                        ))
                    GROUP BY uta.UserAbsenceID

                UNION 
                    SELECT ut.DATE_ AS StartDate, ut.DATE_ AS EndDate FROM user_timesheets ut
                        INNER JOIN moments  m ON m.UserTimesheetsID = ut.UserTimesheetsID
                    WHERE 
                        ut.DATE_ BETWEEN  '2020-06-06' AND  '2020-06-06' + INTERVAL '1' DAY 
                        AND ut.user_id = 1
            ) a
                  GROUP BY a.StartDate,a.EndDate
```

Here is what kind of result I expect in output

```
StartDate      EndDate
'2020-03-05', '2020-03-26'
'2020-01-10', '2020-01-10'
```

After couple of hours I try to modify a query a little bit and split query into two little peaces

First part of query works fine

```
SELECT uta.StartDate, uta.EndDate FROM user_timesheets_absence  uta
                            LEFT JOIN users  u ON u.UserID = uta.UserID
                            WHERE uta.UserID = 1
                            AND uta.Approved = 1
                            AND 
                                ((
                                    '2020-JAN-30' >= uta.StartDate
                            AND
                                    '2020-FEB-06' <= uta.EndDate
                                )
                            OR
                                (
                                    '2020-JAN-30' <= uta.StartDate
                            AND
                                    '2020-AUG-31' >= uta.StartDate
                                ))
                            GROUP BY uta.UserAbsenceID,uta.StartDate, uta.EndDate
```

Second part of query work as belowe

```
SELECT ut.DATE_ AS StartDate, ut.DATE_ AS EndDate FROM user_timesheets ut
                                INNER JOIN moments  m ON m.UserTimesheetsID = ut.UserTimesheetsID
                            WHERE 
                                ut.DATE_  BETWEEN '2020-01-30' AND '2020-02-06' --+ INTERVAL '1' DAY 
                                AND ut.user_id = 1
```

When I add `)a` and  `GROUP BY` and INTERVAL '1' DAYS I get error message

```
  SELECT uta.StartDate, uta.EndDate FROM user_timesheets_absence  uta
                            LEFT JOIN users  u ON u.UserID = uta.UserID
                            WHERE uta.UserID = 1
                            AND uta.Approved = 1
                            AND 
                                ((
                                    '2020-JAN-30' >= uta.StartDate
                            AND
                                    '2020-FEB-06' <= uta.EndDate
                                )
                            OR
                                (
                                    '2020-JAN-30' <= uta.StartDate
                            AND
                                    '2020-AUG-31' >= uta.StartDate
                                ))
                            GROUP BY uta.UserAbsenceID,uta.StartDate, uta.EndDate

                        UNION 
                            SELECT ut.DATE_ AS StartDate, ut.DATE_ AS EndDate FROM user_timesheets ut
                                INNER JOIN moments  m ON m.UserTimesheetsID = ut.UserTimesheetsID
                            WHERE 
                                ut.DATE_  BETWEEN '2020-01-30' AND '2020-02-06'  --+ INTERVAL '1' DAY 
                                AND ut.user_id = 1
```

Comment: The problem is with the first union where you do `GROUP BY uta.UserAbsenceID` but the select clause doesn't use any aggregate function .

Comment: It would help people to answer appropriately if you could provide additional information in the form of a minimal reproducible example. In particular here, we're missing sample data and expected output from your query.  Please check the following link for suggestions 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: If you have a query with two different GROUP BY's, divide the query into two and see which one it is causing problems. Then show us that query, not the big query. [mcve]

Comment: Either if I change and use `UNION ALL` I get same error, also when I change `GROUP BY` to `ORDER BY` same error happened.

Comment: @jarlh The problem is that first and second query doesn't work !

Comment: It's still easier to solve two small problems than one big problem.

Comment: I don't think that's the expected result when your query looks for `2020-06-06`

Comment: I mean, I just random type `StartDate` and `EndDate` value

Comment: Again: `'2020-06-06'` is a **string**, not a date - you cannot add an `INTERVAL` to a string!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UNION` operator already makes a distinct result set, so `GROUP BY` is not needed. You can simplify the query to this one:

```
SELECT uta.StartDate, uta.EndDate 
FROM user_timesheets_absence uta
    LEFT JOIN USERS  u ON u.UserID = uta.UserID
WHERE uta.UserID = 1
    AND uta.Approved = 'true'
    AND (
        ('2020-06-06' >= uta.StartDate AND '2020-06-06' <= uta.EndDate)
        OR ('2020-06-06' <= uta.StartDate AND '2020-06-06' >= uta.StartDate)
    )
  GROUP BY uta.UserAbsenceID
UNION 
SELECT ut.DATE_ AS StartDate, ut.DATE_ AS EndDate 
FROM user_timesheets ut
    INNER JOIN moments  m ON m.UserTimesheetsID = ut.UserTimesheetsID
WHERE 
    ut.DATE_ BETWEEN  '2020-06-06' AND  '2020-06-06' + INTERVAL '1' DAY 
    AND ut.user_id = 1
```

The problem is this one:

```
SELECT uta.StartDate, uta.EndDate 
FROM user_timesheets_absence uta
...
GROUP BY uta.UserAbsenceID
```

For me it is not clear what you are looking for, so I cannot provide a solution. Perhaps `SELECT MIN(uta.StartDate), MAX(uta.EndDate)` but that's just a guess.

There are some more flaws in your query.

```
('2020-06-06' <= uta.StartDate AND '2020-06-06' >= uta.StartDate)
```

is useless. Assuming you did not a typo at column names, this expression is equal to

```
'2020-06-06' = uta.StartDate
```

Then `'2020-06-06'` is a string. **Never** store or compare date/time as strings, use always proper `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` values.

Regarding date values, I assume your query could look like this one:

```
SELECT uta.StartDate, uta.EndDate 
FROM user_timesheets_absence uta
    LEFT JOIN USERS  u ON u.UserID = uta.UserID
WHERE uta.UserID = 1
    AND uta.Approved = 'true'
    AND DATE '2020-06-06' BETWEEN uta.StartDate AND uta.EndDate
  GROUP BY uta.UserAbsenceID
UNION 
SELECT ut.DATE_ AS StartDate, ut.DATE_ AS EndDate 
FROM user_timesheets ut
    INNER JOIN moments  m ON m.UserTimesheetsID = ut.UserTimesheetsID
WHERE 
    ut.DATE_ BETWEEN DATE '2020-06-06' AND DATE '2020-06-06' + INTERVAL '1' DAY 
    AND ut.user_id = 1
```

Comment: I still have same problem

Comment: As stated, I don't know what you like to get, so I can point out only the error but not an solution.

Comment: What do you need to provide solution ? You need table definition and data ? Am I right ?

Comment: No, `SELECT uta.StartDate, uta.EndDate FROM ... GROUP BY uta.UserAbsenceID` is simply pointless. I have no idea what you like to get.

Comment: I post in my question what I need to get. You can check

Comment: After couple of hours try to solve problem and try to find error I notice one think. When I split query in two part it works but when I add `)a` and `GROUP BY ` I get error message

Answer (score 0):

Neither query uses an aggregate function, so GROUP BY can't be used.
As asked before, what is your intended purpose of the GROUP BY?

Comment: After couple of hours try to solve problem and try to find error I notice one think. When I split query in two part it works but when I add )a and GROUP BY  I get error message